# How to fix gpg not available error?

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, software-sources, gnupg

I am trying to kickstart an Ubtuntu installtion using an existing one.

I rsynced the home dir and am now in the process of [duplicating the installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages). Since I have some extra ppa in my setup, I copy pasted the content of `/etc/apt/` to the new machine.

Yet now I am facing the issue when running `apt-get update`:

```
Fetched 632 B in 8s (71 B/s)                                                   
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B9316A7BC7917B12
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY FC6D7D9D009ED615
```

I tried importing the keys using:

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys B9316A7BC7917B12 FC6D7D9D009ED615
```

which results in:

```
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.XGVtDAfZ4i --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/vincent-c-ponysay.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/webupd8team-y-ppa-manager.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys B9316A7BC7917B12 FC6D7D9D009ED615
gpg: requesting key C7917B12 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: requesting key 009ED615 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key C7917B12: "Launchpad chrislea" not changed
gpg: key 009ED615: "Launchpad PPA for Shutter Team" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 2
gpg:              unchanged: 2
```

Yet the issue still persists. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that adding PPA can be dangerous.

I figured that the two keys were:

- The one key was for shutter, which I fixed by adding:

  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shutter/ppa`
- The other one was the chris lea node.js repository, which I replaced with a different one:

  `curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -`

it autmoatically remove the old chris lea one, and let me proceed with the installation.